# Why the itemListener not automatically triggered after setSelectedIndex(0) is called?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jdialog

`cbTexture.setSelectedIndex(0);` is called at the end 
of the constructor, but it doesn't help
automatically select subtextures
after it. Why?

```
  public class TradeInDialog extends JDialog {

    public TradeInDialog(Database _db) throws SQLException
    {
        ....     
        setupTexture();

        cbTexture.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    selectedTexture = cbTexture.getSelectedIndex()+1;
                    setupSubTexture();
            }
        });
          ....      

         cbTexture.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: what is `cbTexture` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the first call of the `setupSubTexture` method outside of the event handler class, so your code must be like this :

public class TradeInDialog extends JDialog {

```
public TradeInDialog(Database _db) throws SQLException
{
    selectedTexture = 1;
    setupSubTexture();
    setupTexture();

    cbTexture.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                selectedTexture = cbTexture.getSelectedIndex()+1;
                setupSubTexture();
        }
    });

    cbTexture.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in next your first element is selected already, as default, because of that `setupSubTexture();` method isn't executed when you call `cbTexture.setSelectedIndex(0);`. Try `cbTexture.setSelectedIndex(1);` and you see that it works.